# Flashing buttons timing

Tags: javascript

NOTE that I'm very new to this, learned from freeCodeCamp's tutorial on youtube and wanted to try working on something by myself.

I'm trying to write the game Simon, but I'm having trouble with the timing of the flashing buttons.
As of right now, all buttons in the sequence will flash at the same time, while I want them to flash one by one.
I tried using setTimeout in multiple places but with no success...
Can someone help me figure out where a use of setTimeout is missing?

```
var sequence = []; /* array to hold the sequence of colors */
var ind = 0; /* where to user is in the sequence */
var score = 0; /* the user's score */
var midOfSeq = false; /* is the user in the middle of a game? */
var Combo = 0; /* user's combo */
var result_div = document.querySelector(".result"); /* messages for the user */
const TIMEOUT = 600; /* time between flashes */

/* checks the user's progress */
function Simon(num) {
  if (sequence.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  if (num === sequence[ind]) {
    Combo++;
    result_div.innerHTML = "Combo: " + Combo;
    ind++;
    if (ind === sequence.length) {
      result_div.innerHTML = "You beat phase " + sequence.length;
      score++;
      ind = 0;
      midOfSeq = false;
      Combo = 0;
      flashSequence();
    }
  } else {
    result_div.innerHTML =
      "Sorry, you clicked the wrong color. Your score: " +
      score +
      "<br>Press the Start! button to try again, Good luck!";
    score = 0;
    ind = 0;
    Combo = 0;
    sequence = [];
    midOfSeq = false;
  }
}

/* generates a number between 1 and 4 */
function rndChoice() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
}

/* flashes the sequence */
function flashSequence() {
  if (midOfSeq === true) {
    return;
  }
  if (score === 0) {
    result_div.innerHTML = "Game Start!";
    sequence.push(rndChoice());
    flashButton(sequence[0]);
  } else {
    sequence.push(rndChoice());
    for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        flashButton(sequence[i]);
      }, 900);
    }
  }
  midOfSeq = true;
}

/* flashes a button */
function flashButton(id) {
  let a = document.getElementById(id.toString());
  switch (a.id) {
    case "1":
      a.setAttribute("class", "flashBlue");
      setTimeout(function() {
        a.setAttribute("class", "blue");
      }, TIMEOUT);
      break;
    case "2":
      a.setAttribute("class", "flashRed");
      setTimeout(function() {
        a.setAttribute("class", "red");
      }, TIMEOUT);
      break;
    case "3":
      a.setAttribute("class", "flashYellow");
      setTimeout(function() {
        a.setAttribute("class", "yellow");
      }, TIMEOUT);
      break;
    case "4":
      a.setAttribute("class", "flashGreen");
      setTimeout(function() {
        a.setAttribute("class", "green");
      }, TIMEOUT);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: all your setTimeouts begin to timeout at the same time ... they don't wait for each other

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure it will solve everything, but the issue stems from the following, where you are going to call `flashButton` for **all** buttons after `900` milliseconds.

```js
var sequence = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //flashButton(sequence[i]);
    console.log(sequence[i]);
  }, 900);
}
```

Instead, spread out the firing, by increasing the timeout for each button using `900 * (i + 1)`...

```js
var sequence = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //flashButton(sequence[i]);
    console.log(sequence[i]);
  }, 900 * (i + 1));
}
```

I'm using `900 * (i + 1)` (instead of just `900 * i`) otherwise the first button would fire immediately (i.e. `900 * 0` = `0`)

---

I've also noticed that `rndChoice()` returns an integer value, which you put into `sequence`, and it is this value that you pass to `flashButton()`.

Within `flashButton(id)` you use that parameter to call `document.getElementById(id)`... which points to you having the `id` of the elements set to things like `id="1"`, etc.

Unfortunately it is invalid HTML to have a numeric character as the the leading character of the `id` property.

So you should consider changing the `id` and the `document.getElementById` accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! that solved it.
Changed the ids as well, is it valid HTML to have your ids as a single character?

Comment: Yes, it's valid HTML to have a single character `id`... but I'll leave it to you to decide if it's sensible from a development/maintenance point of view.  Good luck with the rest of your project :-)